# .Net Maui ImageSource Not Working If Converted To Byte Array From DrawingView

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm using the CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.DrawingView to capture a customer signature. Once they have finished i hide the DrawingView and display it as in image, so as to not interfere with scrolling. The code used to switch between the editor and the image is:

```
private async void ElEditSignatureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!EditingSignature)
    {
        ElCustomerSignatureImage.IsVisible = false;
        ElCustomerSignatureDraw.IsVisible = true;
        ElEditSignatureButton.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("tick.png");
        EditingSignature = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ElCustomerSignatureDraw.Lines.Count > 0)
        {
            Stream stream = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            SignatureImage = bytes;

            ElCustomerSignatureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));

            ElCustomerSignatureDraw.IsVisible = false;
            ElCustomerSignatureImage.IsVisible = true;
            ElEditSignatureButton.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("pencil.png");
            EditingSignature = false;
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Customer Report", "Signature Required", "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

However when doing this no image is displayed.

If i change it to remove the convertion to byte[] (for use later when submitting) the image works:

```
Stream stream = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

ElCustomerSignatureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

While writing this I found the that following does work:

```
Stream stream = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

ElCustomerSignatureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

Stream stream2 = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

byte[] bytes = new byte[stream2.Length];
stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
SignatureImage = bytes;
```

Does anyone know why the first example doesn't work? I mean a stream of bytes should just be a stream of bytes regardless of it's method of creation.

EDIT: Correction the final option that i said works, the bytes variable has the correct length but the data is all 0s, i'm guessing this is also the problem with the first example.

Comment: Open file with Notepad.  The go to menu File Save As and see the encoding when code works and does not work.  I suspect the encoding of the file is wrong.

Comment: also confirm that `bytes` is non-zero length and contains valid image data

Comment: Correction the final option that i said works, the "bytes" has the correct length but is all 0s
@jdwend Since it's a drawingview it should return image data, not text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the stream.Read instead of the stream.Write. Such as:

```
Stream stream = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

ElCustomerSignatureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

Stream stream2 = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

byte[] bytes = new byte[stream2.Length];
stream2.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
SignatureImage = bytes;
```

Note: if the stream2.Length > int.MaxValue, it will cause an error or data losing.

Comment: I should have known that! Totally my mistake, i though i was "writing" to the byte array from the stream, but no, "reading" from the stream to the byte array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok After much trial and error i found code that poplated both the byte array and the image control correctly:

```
Stream stream = await ElCustomerSignatureDraw.GetImageStream(ElCustomerSignatureImage.Width, ElCustomerSignatureImage.Height);

MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(temp);
SignatureImage = temp.ToArray();

stream.Position = 0;
ElCustomerSignatureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

So for some reason MemoryStream.ToArray() works, but MemoryStream.Write() doesn't. No idea why.